# How to explain data compression using song lyrics

Tags: file, compression

I'm making an educational video about *data compression* that would benefit from little doses of humor. Since most lossless compression operates on the principle of [reducing repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Lossless) I'd like to illustrate that idea by way of song lyrics.

For example, the left side of the following image is an uncompressed song (snippet) from Sia. The compressed version would omit repetitions by calling them out as such.

[image: Two lyric files are shown: on the left the original. On the right, the compressed version. The compressed version substitutes repeat verses with references to the number of repetitions it should have or tagged content present elsewhere]

I'd say that pretty clearly demonstrates this type of compression technique. But it shows that compression adds complexity (by virtue of tagging and referencing repeat sub-sequences). It's also not too compressed which leaves it so I can challenge viewers to explore additional ways of compressing the lyrics (i.e. removing white space, etc).

But there's a problem! The lyrics are boringly real (not to mention copyrighted). So I was thinking it would be more fun to make a caricature of the types of lyrics Sia might write then sell to some other artist (say Beyonce). I was thinking Stackoverflow could help. Reply to this post with a lyric caricature that:

1. Is suitable for twelve-year-olds (PG)
2. Has repetition in it so that the "compressed" version actually looks smaller
3. Is originally yours (not copyrighted)
4. Makes joke of pop music ([because a lot of it is](https://youtu.be/P4DMk9BJyY4?t=373)). [Exhibit A](https://youtu.be/KkGVmN68ByU?t=152)
5. Helps communicate the idea better (i.e. a demonstration of lossy compression?)

In return I will:

1. Read all answers.
2. Give all my reputation (at time of accepting the answer) up to 1500 points (Stackoverflow's bounty limit) to whoever posts the funniest or most upvoted answer (discretion is mine).
3. Award points some time on April 11th
4. Give the "winning" lyricist credit in my instructional video
5. Link that video here

Reply if you're greedy for points but also believe STEM education should be more engaging

## Update 1

I have bountied all my reputation

Comment: Nice job, nice proposal, congrats. Not sure if S.O. is the right place for it... But keep it up! More education, please.

Comment: This probably isn't the right place for your question. If you'd like, you can [ask on meta](//meta.stackoverflow.com) - it may be an interesting discussion.

Comment: Getting that 500 back makes you "Reputation 542 top 0.02% this week". Savour it! Let us know if you post this somewhere else. I'm almost ready. EDESMDSEOEPTIRRTETBNDCSODESSEDG

Answer (score 0):

Okay... so... ahm...

Here is my attempt, toast me if you like.
I'm now to notesoverflow and still learning... 
I can try to write more lyrics if you like, not sure if I understood all the conditions correctly.

Since I'm from Germany and listen to hard gangster rap ( ;) ) only I don't have any clue how American songs are usually structured. I'll try it.

```
Sia, listen, sit down we need to talk.
I know it's not easy in your position 
managing business and the like
check your lyrics -> 0 rhymes
not even a spark of inspiration on your mind.
take my hand, let's go for a walk...
To be honest I have never thought 
that you'd have more than 500 points on this site... jeez...

But while we're here, let's not forget,
being a developer is something I personally regret
I would rather write songs, keep the flow...
I'm like this kid... libmozart... well, now you know...
anyways, I almost forgot – look at the clock
it's time to talk about the plot in this track.

Sia, do you ever think about why there are old classic dvds
with around 10 songs and a few beats 
while there are a few dozen CDs
with around 3000 songs each? mostly pop songs indeed...
because it's really really cheap, to store pop songs using zlib

listen,
You wanna know why?
You wanna know why? 

gzip turns your repeated lyrics into just a handful of bytes
to reduce the size it's not magic am I right? 
you all sound familiar am I right?
jeez, look at your eyes – cold shiver.
even an algorithm doesn't find anything that differs.
```

I guess I covered all points, should I go more into the detail of lossy compression? For compression, there are a few whole sentences that can be compressed (You wanna know why?) and a few words (around, songs, forg_t, jeez etc). It's also 4 am so every spelling mistake is because of lossy compression.

If you're looking for the Eminem kind of developer you may post as SIA yourself or add additional coffee to your bounty.